# How to make a div occupy the remaining space

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have seen a lot of issues of this kind but I'm still unable to fix my particular issue. I have something like

```
<div id="container">
   <img src="image.png"/>
   <div id="menu"><ul>(...)</ul></div>
</div>
```

The problem is I don't know the height of the image, I only want it to be as wide as possible then its height should set automatically keeping the ratio. The "menu" div should be under that image and occupy the remaining height.

```
#container img{
   width:100%;
}

#menu{
   width:100%;
}

#menu li{
   height:50%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/v6b3S/

Comment: you can use the jquery function to set the height and width.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set a definitive height on at least one of the two objects.  If you want to ensure your not clipping the image use background image attributes: http://jsfiddle.net/v6b3S/4/

```
#container{
    height: 750px;
    overflow:hidden;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#top-image {
    display: block;
    background: url('http://eofdreams.com/data_images/dreams/image/image-09.jpg') center center no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
}
#menu{
   width:100%;
    height:50%;
   border: 1px solid red;
}

#page{
    height:100%;
}
#a{
    background-color:black;
}

#b{
    background-color:red;
}

#c{
    background-color:blue;
}

#d{
    background-color:yellow;
}
li{
    list-style:none;   
    display:block;
    height:100%;
    background-size: 100%;
    width:25%;
    float:left;
}
span{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    display:block;
}
ul{
 height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work. The menu doesn't occupy all the space available.

Comment: It doesn't work neither. The menu is as height as its parent, so there is an overflow.

Comment: Can you make a fiddle so I can see what your trying to accomplish

Comment: OK I just made one : http://jsfiddle.net/v6b3S/ There are images in the _li_'s in the actual code but I replaced them with text.

Comment: I replaced the texts with spans with colored backgrounds.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/v6b3S/2/ This seems to work for me, perhaps I'm not understanding what your question is.

Comment: Ah I see the edit, and your going to be filling the bottom part with images as well?

Comment: You can see that I made 4 _li_s, but only half of the first two is visible http://jsfiddle.net/v6b3S/1/

Comment: I actually want the size of the images to be set based on the remaining space available so that everything is visible.

Comment: Yes, there will be just 4.

Comment: Sorry it didn't really help. I think the best way to do that is to use JavaScript, so that will I do until I find a better solution. Thanks anyway.